# In Android Studio how do you make use of a font-family xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, fonts

I have two variations of a font that I want to use in my app. IBM Plex Sans Regular (weight 400) and IBM Plex Sans SemiBold (weight 600). So I created an xml file in the font directory like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/ibm_plexsans_regular"/>
    <font app:fontWeight="600" app:font="@font/ibm_plexsans_semibold" />
</font-family>
```

And in the themes.xml I added this font family:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/ibm_plexsans</item>
</style>
```

I want the Regular font to be automatically applied to any regular text in the app and the SemiBold font to be automatically applied to any bold text in the app. Instead all text in the app is now using the Regular font and even if I specifically tell it to use the SemiBold font it won't use it. For example this TextView still uses the regular font:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Rate"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ibm_plexsans_semibold"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />
```

I want this TextView to use the SemiBold font. How would I do that?